# What made The O'Neill a better weapon against Replicators?

Tags: stargate, technology, stargate-sg1

In S04E01 of "Stargate: SG-1", Carter visits the Asgard homeworld and sees that they're building a new class of ship. The prototype vessel is named "The O'Neill" and Thor states that it is the most advanced vessel the Asgard have ever constructed. He also says that it's the first ship designed to combat the Replicators. It's shiny, almost chrome-looking, and is roughly 30% bigger than a normal Asgard vessel. In the image below, a normal vessel is in the foreground and the prototype is some distance in the background:

[image]

Unfortunately, we never see it in action since

> the unfinished ship gets piloted out on remote and blown up in the same episode.

Given that the energy-based weapons of the Asgard had no effect on Replicators, and that they literally eat any ships they can reach, I'm curious as to how exactly the vessel was supposed to be better than the existing Asgard vessels.

**Has any source mentioned what exactly made The O'Neill better for fighting Replicators?**

Comment: Bigger, more powerful, better. Filled with all their latest advancements and enhancements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Amongst other advancements, such as faster hyperdrive, stronger and more efficient shields, and a significantly stronger hull, *[O'Neill-class](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/O%27Neill-class_ship)* ships carried an armament of advanced [Ion Guns](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ion_gun).

Bolts from these upgraded weapons were designed to refract and split on contact with a ship's shielding, allowing them to bypass the shield completely and strike a target multiple times with charged plasma. This allowed them to penetrate Replicator shielding and hit the Replicator blocks with high amounts of force, the only thing known to actually damage them, since they seemed to be immune (or at least very quickly adapt to) all forms of energy. They likely got the idea after seeing how effective relatively primitive Tau'ri weaponry was at dealing with them.

The weaponry was also stated to be effective against Anubis' upgraded Ha'tak vessels, but this was never shown.

It was also fairly ineffective against Ori ships, though we've not seen Asgard vs Ori in a 1v1 situation.

The weaponry became obsolete when the Asgard perfected their Plasma Cannon technology, which was installed on the *Odyssey* (*SG-1: Unending*), and later the *Daedelus* and the *Apollo* (*SGA: Be all my sins remember'd*).

Basically, *O'Neill-class* ships had big guns, but nothing like an ARG or other technology that's specifically anti-replicator.

Comment: Source/citation?